# What is 100. and how is it distinct from 100?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I've recently been seeing a lot of queries where `100.` is used instead of `100`. For example, `CAST(100. * foo) AS NUMERIC(5,2)`.

But what exactly is `100.`? It's obviously some sort of syntactic sugar, presumably for "100 the double, not 100 the int", but I can't find its documentation anywhere so I can't be sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using 100. (or 100.0) is used to prevent integer mathematics.

In t-sql every data type has an [order of precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) with decimal being higher than integer. By specifcying the literal value as a decimal on any part of the expression the calculation is performed implicitely as a decimal.

```
select 100  / 6 /* = 16 */
select 100. / 6 /* = 16.666666 */
```

Comment: Very good, but is there any documentation saying that `100.` means `100.0`?

Comment: @J.Mini See: [Constants](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/constants-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#decimal-constants).

Comment: @J.Mini the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/constants-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#decimal-constants) states "decimal constants are represented by a string of numbers... and contain a decimal point." I guess this is something you simply encounter by trying; and now you know too!

Comment: One other case that you unexpectedly get a `decimal` is `2147483648` (or any other integer out of range for `int`) - which gives a `decimal(10,0)` rather than a `bigint` as this behaviour predates `bigint` being added to the product. So `select 2147483648/5` doesn't give integer division but `select 2147483647/5` does

Comment: Aside: Another favorite bit of _enhanced arithmetic_ is `select 30 / 2 / 5; select 30 / -2 / 5;`. A benefit of [operator precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/operator-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) having unary negation at the same level as addition and subtraction (`3`) rather than at the same level as bitwise NOT (`1`).